# Syncing Users' information between SharePoint and Active Directory, when Users' accounts on SP & AD are not similar

Tags: 2013, powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, administration

I am facing a problem regarding the users' information inside the `userdisp.aspx` Page, not being in-sync with Active Directory.

Now we have the following settings:-

1. SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm with enterprise edition.
2. we did not configure any connection inside the User Profile managed service.

now the problem i am facing is as follow:-

1. when i click on a username inside sharepoint, i got mainly 3 info about the user  inside the "userdisp.aspx" Page as follow:-

   - Account
   - Name
   - Work Email.
     [image]
2. now sometimes the Name and Work email are being out of sync with Active Directory. so i find this script which i can run on site collection basses, which will update the Work Email and Name inside SP to match AD:-

> Get-SPUser –Web "http://servername/sites/WikiSite" | Set-SPUser
>   –SyncFromAD

3. the above script have worked well on many users, but it raised the following exception on all the users which have their Accounts values inside SP not equal to their Accounts on AD:-

> ```
> Set-SPUser : Cannot get the full name or e-mail address of user "i:0#.w|ad-****\****.****".
> At line:1 char:60
> + Get-SPUser –Web "http://servername/sites/WikiSite" | Set-SPUser –SyncFromA ...
> +                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletSetUser:SPCmdletSetUser) [Set-SPUser],
> ```
>
> SPException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletSetUser

so i have concluded that the above script will base its sync on the Account values inside SP & AD. and as a result if the Account on SP & AD are not equal the script will fail to sync those users' info.

so my questions are:-

1. is there a way i can sync the Account values between SP & AD? so before running my above script, i can sync the Users' Accounts?
2. i noted this behavior by chance. is that i use to have a user whose Account was updated inside AD. and as a result his Account on SP was not equal his Account on AD. but when i added the user inside a sharepoint group, i noted that his Account on SP got updated to match his Account on AD.. so what is the relation between adding a user to a SP group and having his Account updated inside SP. and could i benefit from this to Sync all the users' accounts between SP and AD??

Comment: What you mean by update in AD? which property updated? is the SID changed?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP by "update in AD" i mean , updating the Account for the user. now in SharePoint's `userdisp.asp` page there is a field named "Account". and for some users this account will be different based on the site collection, this is caused when the user's account is changed from AD.. now if by SID you mean `NameIdIssuer` then no it will not be changed, as on AD they did not create new user they just update its account. did you get my question?

Comment: Why are you not just configuring UPSA sync? You're creating more work for yourself where there is already a solution built into SharePoint.

Comment: @TrevorSeward yes i agree with you .. but at this stage we are not planning to configure UPSA.. and need to sync based on powershell

Comment: Well, `Set-SPUser -SyncFromAD` is your only method then. It's on a per-Site Collection basis, as well, so you'll have to enumerate each user on each SC. If the sAMAccountName (or whatever your login identifier is) changes, you need to use `Move-SPUser`. Setting up UPSA sync is about a 5 minute process. Much quicker than PoSh.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so if i configure UPSA and the account is changed inside AD, the will the UPSA handle this for me? second question i have is regarding my original second point, which is about why adding a user to a sharepoint security group have automatically update its account inside sharepoint?

Comment: The process for UPSA is handling AD -> UPSA. There are two SharePoint Sync timer jobs which process UPSA -> Site Collections. UPSA will also handle migrating users when it finds a matching identity (e.g. sAMAccountName).

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you advice more on your last comment please? as i did not understand it/

Comment: Implement UPSA sync. It will solve all of your concerns.

Comment: @TrevorSeward the issue is that i always try to keep things simple in sharepoint.. now in our case we do not require having a full sync for the properties such as image, job title, etc.. what i need is just to keep the based info email, display name and account name is sync between SP & AD.. that why i did not involve my self in configuring UPSA..

Comment: But you're making things significantly more complicated by attempting to re-invent the wheel. AD Import is extremely simple to set up. Get a service account, give it Replicate Directory Changes in AD at the forest root, then set up your sync connection in the UPSA. That's it.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so can i grant our sharepoint farm account "Replicate Directory Changes" in AD? or it is better to create a separate service account? and for this service account it should be part of sharepoint farm is this correct?

Comment: It's best practice to create a separate account specifically for sync'ing from AD. It will not be a SharePoint Managed Account.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so i can inform our system admin to provide me with a service account which have ""Replicate Directory Changes" permission on AD, but i read that this account should also be part of the sharepoint farm group ? is this correct? second point ,now in our case configuring AD import will be sufficient,as there is no need to do a full User profile sync, as we do not want to allow end users to update their AD account.. so will AD import work for my case?

Comment: third question. now let say the user's account (login name) got changed inside AD, and i run the AD import, will the AD import treat this  user as a new user? or it is smart enough to update the account on SP for the same user? fourth question, do u know why adding a user to a sharepoint security group will update its account on SP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73492/discussion-between-trevor-seward-and-john-g).